# Junos complex regular expressions question

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I saw this explanation in the JNCIS study guide book ch1 (community regex examples) and i'm a bit confused:

^65000:.{2,3}$ - AS number is 65000, community value is **any 2 or 3 digit number** ex. 65000:**123**, 65000:**16**, and 65000:**999**

^65010:45.{2}9$ - AS number is 65010. The community value is a five-digit number that begins with 45 and ends with 9. **The third and fourth digits are any single number repeated twice**  ex. 65010:45**11**9, 65010:45**99**9, and 65010:45**33**9.

**If** .{2} means any single number repeated twice, **then** i'd have argued .{2,3} if any single number repeated at least twice and at most thrice and not any 2 or 3 digit number as explained in the book.

What is the right interpretation of these 2 regex ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a quick'n'dirty lab and it would appear that the *first* example is actually correct, rather than the second.

The first example, I've got three routes being received, each tagged with a community of `65000:123`, `65000:999` or `65000:16`:

```
{primary:node0}
root@lab-srx240h> show route table CE3.inet.0 community ^65000:.{2,3}$ detail

CE3.inet.0: 7 destinations, 7 routes (7 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
3.3.3.3/32 (1 entry, 1 announced)
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-101
                Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 1383
                Address: 0x15d464c
                Next-hop reference count: 8
                Source: 192.168.88.3
                Next hop: 192.168.88.3 via reth4.100, selected
                State: <Active Ext>
                Peer AS: 65505
                Age: 7:34
                Task: BGP_65505.192.168.88.3+179
                Announcement bits (1): 0-KRT
                AS path: 65505 65505 I
                Communities: 65000:123 target:65505:1
                Accepted
                Localpref: 100
                Router ID: 192.168.6.1

192.168.5.0/24 (1 entry, 1 announced)
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-101
                Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 1383
                Address: 0x15d464c
                Next-hop reference count: 8
                Source: 192.168.88.3
                Next hop: 192.168.88.3 via reth4.100, selected
                State: <Active Ext>
                Peer AS: 65505
                Age: 7:34
                Task: BGP_65505.192.168.88.3+179
                Announcement bits (1): 0-KRT
                AS path: 65505 I
                Communities: 65000:999 target:65505:1
                Accepted
                Localpref: 100
                Router ID: 192.168.6.1

192.168.88.0/31 (1 entry, 1 announced)
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-101
                Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 1383
                Address: 0x15d464c
                Next-hop reference count: 8
                Source: 192.168.88.3
                Next hop: 192.168.88.3 via reth4.100, selected
                State: <Active Ext>
                Peer AS: 65505
                Age: 7:34
                Task: BGP_65505.192.168.88.3+179
                Announcement bits (1): 0-KRT
                AS path: 65505 I
                Communities: 65000:16 target:65505:1
                Accepted
                Localpref: 100
                Router ID: 192.168.6.1
```

The second example I've got a route tagged with `65010:45129` (not `65010:45119` as per the book) and I still get a match:

```
{primary:node0}
root@lab-srx240h> show route table CE3.inet.0 community ^65010:45.{2}9$ detail
CE3.inet.0: 7 destinations, 7 routes (7 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
1.0.0.10/32 (1 entry, 1 announced)
        *BGP    Preference: 170/-101
                Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 1383
                Address: 0x15d464c
                Next-hop reference count: 8
                Source: 192.168.88.3
                Next hop: 192.168.88.3 via reth4.100, selected
                State: <Active Ext>
                Peer AS: 65505
                Age: 2:23
                Task: BGP_65505.192.168.88.3+179
                Announcement bits (1): 0-KRT
                AS path: 65505 65505 I
                Communities: 65010:45129 target:65505:1 origin:65505:1
                Accepted
                Localpref: 100
                Router ID: 192.168.6.1
```

So yes, `.{2}` means *any two* characters and `.{2,3}` means *any two-to-three* characters.

Comment: Excellent - so the book is wrong or ambiguous and we're all sane.

Comment: I had a look online for the errata mentioned in the book - http://www.corerouting.net, which is now dead (heck the book is 14 years old).  Even back-tracked with the arhive.org wayback machine, but it shows no corrections.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure about any Junos specialties but with 'standard' regex, `.{2}` matches *any two characters*, repeating or not.

If you'd need two of the same character it should be looking something like `(.)\1`.

`.{2,3}` matches two or three of any character (same or different).

Comment: Correct for standard regex and it's what i though was right for junos too but the book's example somewhat contradicts, thus my question. Thanks